# How to add external template to a Visual Studio project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I create a project in Visual Studio and I want to add an external template on it.

How can I add it?

Comment: Visual studio template?  If so project template or item template?  If not, what specifically?  Can you edit your answer to provide more details?

Comment: I used Microsoft visual studio 2010 to make a website and I create a new project inside it and I want to add a template

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though, add a template to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a template of your project, see this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247120%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  For item templates, see this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  For the later, you basically create the configuration files defined in the article, ZIP them up, then create the template at the following path:

> C:\Users[USERNAME]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates[LANGUAGE]

Replace the bracketed items with your name and development language (Visual C#, Visual Basic, etc.)  You have to restart Visual Studio to see it.